# What does the phrase "be over someone's shit" mean?

Tags: meaning, slang

Could you tell me what the phrase *be over one's shit* mean? For example:

> The math teacher was **over my shit** today.

Comment: Do you really want to know about **over my shit**, or did you mean to type ***all*** **over my shit** in the example sentence? (In common interpretation, they actually mean different things.) Did you make up the sentence, or did you actually see it used exactly like that somewhere?

Comment: I saw in "Breaking Bad", but that sentence is me. Could you please tell me what they mean?

Comment: In general, and this is still a bit vague and short, so I'm not turning it into an answer yet, I would look at it this way—I'll change the example a bit: (1) *I'm over your shit.* → I'm finished being upset with your antics. Let's get on with things. (2) *I'm **all** over your shit.* → I'm in your face and calling you to task about something; if you're there, so am I, checking up on you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following three sentences all have different meaning:

> (1A) The math teacher ***was over my shit*** today.
>
> (2A) The math teacher was ***all over my shit*** today.
>
> (3A) The math teacher was ***done with my shit*** today.

Phrases of the form "***[pronoun] shit***" can be replaced with one the following three alternatives:

> 1. [Pronoun] clothing or other personal belongings
> 2. [Pronoun] inapropriate behavior, shenanigans, or goofing-off
> 3. [Pronoun] emotional turmoil
> 4. "[Pronoun] case"
> 5. "[Pronoun] drama"

After replacing "my shit" with phrases which are easier for well-educated people to understand, we obtain:

> (1B) The math teacher was over my inappropriate behavior today.
>
> (2B) The math teacher was all over my case today.
>
> (3B) The math teacher was done with my inappropriate behvior today.

We can further translate these quotes from bad English into Good English.. To "***get over***" somthing means to forgive someone. Likewise, saying that "The math teacher ***was over my shit*** today" has somthing to do with forgiveness about 10% of the time. 90% of the time, an antonym of "forgive" would be more appropriate.

> (1C) iday, rhe math teacher had gotten over, and was no longer upset by,  my past inappropriate behavior.
>
> (2C) The math teacher badgered me quite a lot today, and nit-picked everything.
>
> (3C) The math teacher was impatient with me today. They were done with (finished tolerating) my inappropriate behvior.

Usually, the [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=G%20kid) is useful for this sort if thing. However, as of September 2022, there was no entry in the Urban Dictionary for "***over my shit***"